# How to draw a grid of items depending on GeometryReader

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI and as an end goal of the current project, I would like to draw bezier paths, each on its own layer, which could be modified on interaction (e.g. change color on tap) and also be able to resize the whole group on magnification gesture.

For testing purpose, I wanted to create a grid of rounded squares (which are going to be replaced by arbitrary bezier path in the future) and display the grid on the screen.

The code is the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PathView: View {
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        let overlayContent = VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .padding()
        GeometryReader {
            geometry in
            let rectangles: [GridItem] = getSquareGrid(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, count: 10)
            var rects = ZStack {
                ForEach(rectangles) { rectangle in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: rectangle.cornerRadius, style: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.continuous/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .fill(rectangle.color)
                        .frame(width: rectangle.size, height: rectangle.size, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .offset(x: rectangle.offsetX, y: rectangle.offsetY)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("rectangle \(rectangle.id) tapped")
                        }
                }
            }.scaledToFit()
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                        .onChanged({ (scale) in
                            self.scale = scale.magnitude
                        })
                        .onEnded({ (scaleFinal) in
                            self.scale = scaleFinal
                        }))
            return rects.drawingGroup()
                .overlay(overlayContent, alignment: .topLeading)
        }
    }
}

struct GridItem: Identifiable {
    let size: CGFloat
    let offsetX: CGFloat
    let offsetY: CGFloat
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let id = UUID()
    
    init(size: CGFloat, offsetX: CGFloat, offsetY: CGFloat, cornerRadius: CGFloat, color: Color) {
        self.size = size
        self.offsetX = offsetX
        self.offsetY = offsetY
        self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.color = color
    }
}

func getSquareGrid(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, count: Int) -> [GridItem] {
    var rectangleArray: [GridItem] = []
    let size = min(width, height)
    let rectangleSize = round(size/CGFloat(count))
    for row in 0...count - 1 {
        for column in 0...count - 1 {
            let rect = GridItem(size: rectangleSize, offsetX: CGFloat(column) * rectangleSize, offsetY: CGFloat(row) * rectangleSize, cornerRadius: 25.0, color: Color.red)
            
            rectangleArray.append(rect)
        }
    }
    return rectangleArray
}

struct PathView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PathView()
    }
}
```

This version is unable to build due to the following error:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to
> disambiguate

In order to get the available space dimensions, I used GeometryReader and passed its dimensions to the function getSquareGrid().

Does anyone know how to appropriately use GeometryReader in this case or anyhow get the dimensions in order to fill the available screen with generated grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not testable due to absent dependencies, but try the following

```
let drawnRects = rects.drawingGroup()
return drawnRects
    .overlay(overlayContent, alignment: .topLeading)
```

replace with

```
rects.drawingGroup()
    .overlay(overlayContent, alignment: .topLeading)
```

*Update: actually if I replace `overlayContent` with just `Text("test")` it complied well.*

Comment: I tried to apply your suggestion and the error remained unchanged. Also, I added missing dependency and tried to replaced it with just Text("test") but still didn't work.  Do you know what might be wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: In your updated code just remove `return` (when I wrote `replace` I meant exactly replace) ... and btw, I used Xcode 12 for testing, just in case.